# fundamental matrix keeps changing in matlab but same using open cv.what might be the reason?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, matlab-cvst

I have calculated fundamental matrix using the function shown below

```
[fMatrix, epipolarInliers, status] = estimateFundamentalMatrix(...
   matchedPoints1, matchedPoints2, 'Method', 'RANSAC', ...
   'NumTrials', 10000, 'DistanceThreshold', 0.1, 'Confidence', 99.99);
```

but here in this case fundamental matrix keeps varying each time i run the program.

but when i use the code shown below in open cv i get the same fundamental matrix everytime i run the program.code is shown below

```
 cv::Mat fundamental=cv::findFundamentalMat(cv::Mat(selPointsLeft),cv::Mat(selPointsRight),CV_FM_RANSAC);
```

in both the cases i used surf features to extract the match features.Matchpoints1=selpointsleft and matchpoints2=selpointsright.
What might the reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RANSAC is an abbreviation for "RANdom SAmple Consensus". That said, we must expect the output matrix to change as the samples are randomly picked.

In OpenCV, the values are picked from a uniformly distributed list of random values. Thus we get the same values every time we run the code.

In Matlab, it that seems to pick a completely random value and hence the problem. You will have to check whether there is a way to [random-seed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) the picking of random values, which I am quiet unsure of.

Comment: thanks for the answer.can u please explain what is meant by uniformly distributed list of random values.

Comment: I shall give an example. The rand() function in C produces random number. This function required a seed value to output the number. By default the seed value is the current time. So each time the code gets executed,the random number produced will be different. The seed value could be set manually using srand(). Setting it to a constant value will result in producing the same set of random values everytime to code is executed.

Comment: ok thanks again.so u mean in open cv there is a seed to obtain the random value.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Its value in openCV is 4294967295, ie., the largest possible unsigned 32bit integer.

Comment: so in open cv this number is the seed  and in matlab the seed keeps changing.does it depends on the function ?there might be ways to get single values for matrix if i seed the function in matlab rite?

Comment: Yes. I am not sure whether you could seed the random number generator in matlab

Comment: s = rng;   x = rand(1,5);   rng(s);
y = rand(1,5) this function allow you to control random number generation in matlab